# Update constrains

Tags: ios, swift

Please, help me to solve problem.
I have a func of creating checkboxes. In this function i increase a height of `UIVIew` each time by:

```
self.myView.addSubview(MyCheckbox)
myFrame.origin.y += myFrame.size.height. // This is the Y position of new checkbox. I.m creating a frame with checkbox and it's title inside. It's height depends on checkbox picture height.
self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(self.myView.frame.origin.x, self.myView.frame.origin.y, self.myView.frame.size.width, myFrame.origin.y) // And this is the updated frame with new Height.
```

In that case i have `myView` with checkboxes inside and with new height(note: it has height 1.0 by default in interface builder)
But other `UIView` which is located below myView is standing still oh his place.
How to update the height constraint of myView? Or maybe autoresize it when I creating checkboxes?

Thanks to all!

Comment: create an IBOutlet for your constraint and set your `constraint.constant` to be whatever the new height should be

Comment: can you include more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle this, drag your constraint in interface builder to your class and make an IBOutlet.

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then set it by setting `constraint.constant` like so:

```
heightConstraint.constant = 50
```